# Controlling Shift Registers with RaspberryPi - erratic results

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to blink some LEDs by controlling a Shift Register (74HC595) with a RaspberryPi. I've basically rewritten [this Arduino code](http://bildr.org/2011/02/74hc595/) in Python, but what I had anticipated to be a straight-forward code has been erratic at best.

When run, the first pattern works fine but the second pattern only works for LEDs 4-8. Decreasing the delay between blinks yields even worse results. I'm running Raspian Jessie on a RPi 2 model B. Python 2.7. Register and LEDs are powered by a separate 5V power supply, everything shares common GND.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## import GPIO lib
import time ## import time lib


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) ## SER
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT) ## RCLK
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT) ## SRCLK

num_74hc595s = int(1)
num_pins = num_74hc595s * 8

registers = [False]*num_pins

def setPin(index, value):
    registers[index] = value

def clearRegisters():
    for i in range(num_pins-1, -1, -1):
        registers[i] = False

def writeRegisters():
    GPIO.output(11, False)

    for i in range(num_pins-1, -1, -1):
        GPIO.output(12, False)

        val = registers[i]

        GPIO.output(7, val)
        GPIO.output(12, True)

    GPIO.output(11, True)

##turn on odd LEDs
clearRegisters()
writeRegisters()

setPin(0, True)
setPin(2, True)
setPin(4, True)
setPin(6, True)

writeRegisters()

print (registers)

time.sleep(1)

clearRegisters()
writeRegisters()

setPin(1, True)
setPin(3, True)
setPin(5, True)
setPin(7, True)

writeRegisters()

print (registers)

time.sleep(1)

clearRegisters()
writeRegisters()

for i in range(0, 8): #lights up LEDs sequentially

    clearRegisters()
    writeRegisters()

    setPin(i, True)

    writeRegisters()

    time.sleep(2)


GPIO.cleanup()
print ("Dunzo")
```

The first bit